# Max element from more than 2 columns of Dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe as "w":

```
       A       B
0  Alex  Benedict
1  John       NaN
```

I want to find the maximum from these 2 columns and store it in "A" column
I used the following method:

```
w["A"] = w[['A','B']].max(axis=1)
    A         B
0 NaN  Benedict
1 NaN       NaN
```

I don't want this output of "NaN" in the "A" column. How should I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with `max` per rows with removing missing values:

```
w['A'] = w[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().max(), axis=1)
print (w)
          A         B
0  Benedict  Benedict
1      John       NaN
```

Comment: What if there is one more NaN instead of Alex?

Comment: @SolankiKetul - It working also nice. Also if both values `NaN`s per rows it working.

Comment: @SolankiKetul - btw, why do you need `max` of strings?

Comment: @jezrael : This solution is pretty slow for big dataframes. Do you have any suggestions to improve performance? I am trying to do this for data types such as string and datetime.

Comment: @StevenVanDorpe - hmmm, it is not so easy, because this is non standard data - strings and  need maximum.

Comment: @jezrael : I understand. It would probably be more feasible to try to convert the data to numeric values. The problem is my data is 99.9% numeric (Customer id's), but some of them - older ones - still have a letter in it. These values hinder conversion to a numerical data type. Do you have any ideas to surpass this?

Comment: @StevenVanDorpe - So data are same like in this question? Need max of multiple rows? Then I suggest create 2 Dataframes - first for numeric, second for non numeric and processing separately. Last concat together

Answer (score 1):

The `nanmax()` function of `numpy` does the job

`w['A'] = w[['A', 'B']].apply(np.nanmax)`

Comment: `TypeError: ("'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'", 'occurred at index B')`

Comment: TypeError: ('unorderable types: str() >= float()', 'occurred at index 2'). Gave me this error